# compute the Wold representation of this process

Tags: self-study, stationarity, decomposition

I want to find the Wold representation of $y_t = e_t + \alpha e_{t-1} e_{t-2}$, but I'm having difficulties with the product.

For instance, I tried:
$$
y_t = e_t + \alpha e_{t-1}e_{t-2}  \pm e_{t-1}^2 \pm \frac{\alpha^2}{4}e_{t-2}^2 = e_t - e_{t-1}^2 - \frac{\alpha^2}{4}e_{t-2}^2 + \left(e_{t-1}+\frac{\alpha}{2}e_{t-2}\right)^2,
$$
but of course the last term is a problem... Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, please add the [self-study] tag.

Comment: didn't know that existed. thanks for letting me know